# How to make the caption of table* left align

Tags: tables, align, captions

I want to make the caption of `table*` left align, but I try many ways that can not deal with the problem.
this: [image]
I use Elsevier format.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\caption{The performance evaluation of different models on test set.}\label{tbl3}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Method}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GSN}                       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LS}                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OTHERS}                    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg.}                      \\ \cline{2-13}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        \\ \hline
J48                                          & 67.5          & 64.4          & 65.9          & 64.5          & 73.1          & 68.5          & 86.1          & 84.7          & 85.4          & 79.3          & 79.1          & 79.2          \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I have tried `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}`
and

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=none]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  labelsep=newline,
  singlelinecheck=false,
}
```

But they all not correct.

Pls help me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With your code fragment is not possible to reproduce your problem, Please instead of fragments provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: IIRC, elsevier uses a custom caption, which means that they have gone to a lot of effort to keep people from formatting their own captions.

Comment: It is better to provide the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Do please tell us which document class you employ. The `caption` package is incompatible with some document classes.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

Comment: `\FullWidth=454pt` meets your requirement, but not sure how to fix it...sorry....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are more satified with the following table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[width=.95\textwidth,cols=13]
\caption{The performance evaluation of different models on test set.}\label{tbl3}
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{lCCCCCCCCCCCC}
\toprule
Method & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GSN}                       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LS}                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OTHERS}                    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg.}                      \\ 
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
                       & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        & P(\%)         & R(\%)         & F1(\%)        \\ 
\midrule
J48                                          & 67.5          & 64.4          & 65.9          & 64.5          & 73.1          & 68.5          & 86.1          & 84.7          & 85.4          & 79.3          & 79.1          & 79.2          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on @MadyYuvi's comment, I would suggest that you *not* load the `caption` package and, instead, issue the directive

```
\setlength\FullWidth{\textwidth}
```

before `\begin{table*}`. (If you want to make scope of this directive global for the entire document, place it in the preamble.) And, to make the table occupy the full width width (and no more than that!), use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.

I would also recommend that you (a) give the table a more open "look" by omitting all vertical bars and using the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package to create well-spaced horizontal lines and (b) provide more visual structure to the header material by placing the information about unit of measurement to a separate row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\shorttitle{Thoughts}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\FullWidth{\textwidth}
\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Performance evaluation of various models on test set.}\label{tbl3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{c} }
\toprule
Method
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{GSN} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LS} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Others} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Avg.} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
& P & R & F1 & P & R & F1 & P & R & F1 & P & R & F1 \\ 
& (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) \\
\midrule
J48 & 67.5  & 64.4  & 65.9  & 64.5  & 73.1  & 68.5  & 86.1  & 84.7  & 85.4  & 79.3  & 79.1  & 79.2 \\
Naive Bayes & \\
\dots & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```